# How do you reference a foreign key from a razor view page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

New to .net core here and I am going through  razor tutorials and trying to add my own things to it.  I have two tables: Order and Stock.  I can list all Orders or all stocks, but when I want to list all Orders, I want to display the stock name (not the stockID) in the view page (near end of code).  How do you reference the foreign key 'stockID' from the view page?  Here is my code:

```
public class OrderModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OrderName { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal StockUnitCost { get; set; }
    public decimal StockTotalCost { get; set; }
    public decimal WinLoseAmt { get; set; }
    public int StockId { get; set; }

}

 public class StockModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StockName { get; set; }
    public string StockTicker { get; set; }
    public string StockType { get; set; }
    public string Sector { get; set; }
}
```

```
     public class OrderDisplayModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IOrderData _orderData;
        private readonly IStockData _stockData;

        public OrderModel Order { get; set; }
        public List<OrderModel> orderList { get; set; }

        public OrderDisplayModel(IOrderData orderData, IStockData stockData)
        {
            _orderData = orderData;
            _stockData = stockData;
        }

        public async Task OnGet()
        {
            
            orderList = await _orderData.GetOrder();
        }

    }
```

```
    <h1>My Orders</h1>

<table class="'table table-striped">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>Order Name</th>
            <th>Stock</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Cost Basis</th>
            <th>Total Cost</th>
            <th>Open Mkt Gain</th>
            <th>Order Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        

        @foreach (var order in Model.orderList)
        {
           
        <tr>
            <td>@order.OrderName</td>
            <td>@Model.StockPurchased</td>
            <td>@order.StockId</td>
            <td>@order.Quantity</td>
            <td>@order.StockUnitCost</td>
            <td>@order.StockTotalCost</td>
            <td>@order.WinLoseAmt</td>
            <td>@order.OrderDate</td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a virtual property and make it ForeignKey (and InverseProperty if you want to have another virtual collection property from Stock to Orders).
Something like this

```
....
public int StockId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey(nameof(StockId))]
[InverseProperty("Orders")]
public virtual Stock Stock { get; set; }
```

Then, you can either .Include(s=>s.Stock) in you context call and access it like order.Stock.StockName. Or setup Lazy loading (which requires a a bit more work in recent .NET core versions) and you access it without needing to Inclue it.

Comment: thanks for answer. Can you elaborate a bit more on the .Include(s=>s.Stock) in the context call.   I will need to access each stock name for every pass of my orders in the view.

Comment: var orders = _context.Orders.Include(s=>s.Stocks).ToList();
Then, when you go through them with a for each, you'll be able to access the Stock object for each item.

Comment: I added the virtual property and made it a foreignkey but I am having trouble with the context call.  After typing "var orders = _context. " I get a red squigly line telling me the name _context does not exist in the current context. I ctrl . and generated field OrderDisplayModel._context and it added 'private object _context;' . But after doing so, _context does not give me anything useful to chose from.  I don't see Orders, or any of the properties, and I do not see Include as well.  Just FYI I am not using entity framework, I am using Dapper.

Comment: I did assume you were using EF actually. Haven't used Dapper, sorry. Not sure how it manages relationships, if at all. You could obviously use SQL to make the JOIN and fill-out a model with the properties you want, but don't know if there's a better way to do it in Dapper.

Comment: no problem.  Thanks you for your time and effort regardless :)